# Formatting Negative Numbers with Dollar Sign in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, format

I am creating Highcharts from dynamic data and have negative values with dollar signs. But the formatter is showing them like:

$-4,322

When I want:

-$4,322

This is what I am using:

```
pointFormat: 'Year {point.x:.0f}: ${point.y:,.0f}'
```

Can anyone help with that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can switch to the `pointFormatter` function to format it this way.

For example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f21qxLw6/)):

```
pointFormatter: function() {
    var isNegative = this.y < 0 ? '-' : '';
    return 'Year ' + this.x.toFixed(0) + ': ' + isNegative + '$' + Math.abs(this.y.toFixed(0));
}
```